# How can I snap irregular GPS point data to regular points of a route?

Tags: qgis, gdal, r, postgresql, ogr

I have irregular GPS points in several shapefiles with meteorological parameters of a mobile measurement campaign.
In order to compare the different shapefiles I would like to snap the irregular GPS points to predefined waypoints (e.g. regular with 1m distance) of the route.

I was able to prepare the regular points with 1m distance. But how can I assign the values of the irregular GPS points to my artificially created points? The number of GPS points is larger compared to the regular points.

I thought about buffering the regular points and take all GPS points within the buffer to calculate the mean of the measured values. What do you think about this idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "comparing" the shapefiles? What constitutes similar and different shapes? Where do the meteorological parameters come into this comparison? Are you trying to assign values at the met. location points (rain, temp?) to the waypoint locations? Why is snapping an option? Can you not interpolate the met. data and sample from that? eg using kriging or another spatial interpolation?

Comment: During the measurement campaign we drove a fixed route with a measurement car for different time slots. For each time slot I have a single shapefile with the GPS positions and the measured values (air temperature and so on..) - So on on side.. I have this fixed route and on the other side I got slightly varyiing GPS positions in each shape file. Now I want to compare these files.

Comment: You already have "compared" them and found they're different. Now what? Do you want some *measure* of how different they are? Or do you want to summarise or aggregate or snap them all to the same set of points? You need to be precisely clear about what you want to do and why in order for us to figure out if anything is a good idea.

Comment: According to your words I want to snap them all to the same set of points in order to compare the shapefiles since the represent the same route.

Comment: Compare the *measurements* rather than the shape? You have two unobserved functions of location, lets call them A(x,y) and B(x,y), measured at two different sets of locations {a} and {b} to give two sets of observations of A and B. And you want to see how the values of B, originally measured at {b}, interpolated to the {a} locations, compare with the values of A that were measured at {a}? I'd use kriging on B to predict at {a} and then compare means and standard errors to look for significant differences.

Comment: Not directly.. I want to relate the measurements. I have to different sets of locations {a} and {b} (actually many more) but these sets are "similar" (because they represent the same route, but for different time slots (every 3 hour)). Based on these n-sets I want to calculate a diurnal cycle for each position; therefore I have to align these n sets (not the measurements but the location).

Comment: It still sounds like the better approach would be to interpolate the measurements at the  irregular points to the regular gridded points (using eg kriging), unless the locations in {a} and {b} are intended to have a 1-1 relationship (ie they are supposed to be at the same set of ground-truth locations) and the reason the points don't align is measurement error in the location.